# Should we remove [transcendental-numbers]?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag [transcendental-numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transcendental-numbers).

It's currently used on only 2 questions, [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/80832/approximate-the-frans%C3%A9n-robinson-constant) and [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/82604/approximation-of-e). Both are [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) and involve approximating 2 transcendental numbers. (`e` and the Fransén-Robinson constant)

This doesn't appear really to add anything to these challenges, 1 is also tagged math and number and the other is tagged calculus.  Can we burninate it?

Optionally, we can create an [approximation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/approximation) tag for challenges that involve approximating constants. (not sure if this is a good idea, might be too uncommon)

### Update:

I've gone ahead and created a tag (and tag wiki) for [approximation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/approximation).  I also retagged the 2 current [transcendental-numbers] questions with approximation (and removed the old tag).  I'll hold off on retagging the questions listed in @Flip's answer for a bit.

Comment: 'Burninate' is an interesting word.

Comment: @Pavel It's the commonly used word for deleting tags.

Comment: @Easterly Irk The tag may seem to uncommon, but we have a few approximation challenges ready to be retagged.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## We should burninate it, replacing it with a broader [approximation].

Edit: This tag has been created. Questions on this last have been retagged. Other questions that find into this category can be slowly retagged when stumbled across.

---

The two challenges tagged with [transcendental-numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transcendental-numbers) are both about approximating mathematical constant - if we burninate this tag, we can replace it with [approximation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/approximation).

Challenges that would fit under this tag include:

- [Approximate the Fransén-Robinson constant](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/80832/approximate-the-frans%C3%A9n-robinson-constant)
- [Approximation of e](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/82604/approximation-of-e)
- [Monte Carlo estimator of Pi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47759/monte-carlo-estimator-of-pi)
- [Natural Pi #1 - Sand](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/96275/natural-pi-1-sand)
- [Natural Pi #0 - Rock](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/95231/natural-pi-0-rock)
- [Natural Pi #2 - River](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/104655/natural-pi-2-river)
- [Khinchin's constant to as many decimal places as possible in 64 bytes or less](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/34736/khinchins-constant-to-as-many-decimal-places-as-possible-in-64-bytes-or-less)
- [Compute the fibonomial coefficient](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/88923/compute-the-fibonomial-coefficient/88967#88967)

... and many more.

Answer (score 5):

## Yes, we should burninate it.

- It's only used on 2 questions
- Very few numbers are proven transcendental, and it's unlikely a challenge would be to *prove* a number transcendental
- All of the existing challenges (all 2 of them) don't particularly relate to the actual transcendental-ness of the numbers (i.e. the infinite, nonrepeating part) and are basically just evaluate a formula to a certain precision

Answer (score -4):

## No, we shouldn't burninate it

- The tag is relevant to all questions about transcendental numbers, not just proving them
- It may be used on more questions as time goes on
- There is no point to destroying it

Comment: This doesn't really present any arguments for keeping it, other than the second one. The first should probably be a comment on my answer, and the last one is either wrong or pointless. The "point" is to clean up unnecessary tags.